# Having a hard time figuring out where questions should be posted

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I have 2 questions on Programmers:

- [How should I design a security
  module...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29971/how-should-i-design-a-security-module-data-access-controller-in-an-mef-project)
- [How are you using MEF...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29707/how-are-you-using-the-managed-extensibility-framework)

I'm fairly certain I have the 2nd question in the right place. However, as you can see from the comment on the first question, there is concern that it should be on SO.

Well, I was pretty certain that, because I am not including any code, nor expect code in an answer, the question is on the right site.

It makes no difference to me which site the question is on. I am trying to read through FAQs and other questions to get a clear understanding of how I can consistently post to the correct site. Is there a specific link that gives me guidelines comparing what should be on SO vs. Programmers?

Comment: Try to improve that question (first one) to make sure what's your intention. As it is written I would say that belongs to SO. For me it's ease to provide an objective answer, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @bigown: I don't mind if it gets migrated to SO. I thought it would be *somewhat* subjective as there could be several different ways to implement. Can I flag the question to get it migrated?

Comment: Of course you can but I you can let on PSE either. No vote was casted to close/migrate it. I won't take any actions unless you or community request it.